# How to call non blocking function from cocos2d-x callback functions?

Tags: c++, callback, cocos2d-x, nonblocking

i have method inside touchUpInsideAction or touchDragInsideAction cause ControlButton delay or sluggish behavior when button press
im using the ControlButton from the Extensions with cocos2d-x-3.0alpha1
but when i try to call method from the button callbacks
the button press Behavior is stack or sluggish
for example :

```
auto backgroundButton = Scale9Sprite::create("extensions/button.png");
        auto backgroundHighlightedButton = Scale9Sprite::create("extensions/buttonHighlighted.png");

        auto titleButton = LabelTTF::create("Touch Me!", "Marker Felt", 30);

        titleButton->setColor(Color3B(159, 168, 176));

        ControlButton *controlButton = ControlButton::create(titleButton, backgroundButton);
        controlButton->setBackgroundSpriteForState(backgroundHighlightedButton, Control::State::HIGH_LIGHTED);
        controlButton->setTitleColorForState(Color3B::WHITE, Control::State::HIGH_LIGHTED);

        controlButton->setAnchorPoint(Point(0.5f, 1));
        controlButton->setPosition(Point(screenSize.width / 2.0f, screenSize.height / 2.0f));
        addChild(controlButton, 1);


        // Sets up event handlers

        controlButton->addTargetWithActionForControlEvents(this, cccontrol_selector(HelloWorld::touchDownAction), Control::EventType::TOUCH_DOWN);

        controlButton->addTargetWithActionForControlEvents(this, cccontrol_selector(HelloWorld::touchDragInsideAction), Control::EventType::DRAG_INSIDE);
        controlButton->addTargetWithActionForControlEvents(this, cccontrol_selector(HelloWorld::touchDragOutsideAction), Control::EventType::DRAG_OUTSIDE);
        controlButton->addTargetWithActionForControlEvents(this, cccontrol_selector(HelloWorld::touchDragEnterAction), Control::EventType::DRAG_ENTER);
        controlButton->addTargetWithActionForControlEvents(this, cccontrol_selector(HelloWorld::touchDragExitAction), Control::EventType::DRAG_EXIT);
        controlButton->addTargetWithActionForControlEvents(this, cccontrol_selector(HelloWorld::touchUpInsideAction), Control::EventType::TOUCH_UP_INSIDE);
        controlButton->addTargetWithActionForControlEvents(this, cccontrol_selector(HelloWorld::touchUpOutsideAction), Control::EventType::TOUCH_UP_OUTSIDE);
        controlButton->addTargetWithActionForControlEvents(this, cccontrol_selector(HelloWorld::touchCancelAction), Control::EventType::TOUCH_CANCEL);

        // test for issue 2882

        controlButton->addTargetWithActionForControlEvents(this, cccontrol_selector(HelloWorld::touchBitmaskAction),
            Control::EventType::TOUCH_DOWN | Control::EventType::DRAG_INSIDE | Control::EventType::DRAG_OUTSIDE | Control::EventType::DRAG_ENTER | Control::EventType::DRAG_EXIT | Control::EventType::TOUCH_UP_INSIDE | Control::EventType::TOUCH_UP_OUTSIDE | Control::EventType::TOUCH_CANCEL | Control::EventType::VALUE_CHANGED);
```

now i try to call the method from :

```
 void HelloWorld::touchUpInsideAction(Object *sender, Control::EventType controlEvent)
{
    //_displayValueLabel->setString(String::createWithFormat("Touch Up Inside.")->getCString());
    CCLOGWARN("touchUpInsideAction");
    this->pFliteManager->talk("A");
}
```

or from

```
 void HelloWorld::touchDownAction(Object *senderz, Control::EventType controlEvent)
{
    //_displayValueLabel->setString(String::createWithFormat("Touch Down")->getCString());
    CCLOGWARN("touchDownAction");
    this->pFliteManager->talk("A");
}
```

the function is executing great but the button doesn't do the click down effect
why?

Comment: I am confused. Do you have a slow, sluggish or absolutely no press down effect?

Comment: each time something else , its problem with executing none blocking method calls